# Windows phone 8.1 - text from dynamically created textBoxes

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm trying to create table scheme in Windows phone 8.1 but I have problem with saving this. I created table in XAML: Here is code

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="br" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <Grid x:Name="Ahoj" Margin="0,0,-20,-18">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding name}"></TextBox>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding s1}"></TextBox>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding s2}"></TextBox>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding s3}"></TextBox>

                                <TextBox Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding s3}"></TextBox>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding name}"></TextBox>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="6" Text="{Binding s1}"></TextBox>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="7" Text="{Binding s2}"></TextBox>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="8" Text="{Binding s3}"></TextBox>

                                <TextBox Grid.Column="9" Text="{Binding s3}"></TextBox>

                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>

                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

but i don't know how to read values from this dynamically created textBoxes. I need to get the value of all the textbox. I do not need to work with them separately. 
Thanks

**EDIT**

I try to use codes from answers and it work well, but only with first grid. 
I'm creating grid dynamically too. This grid has the same name, but diferent values from Binding.
Code in answer work returning value only from first line textboxes...

[image]

Code - I'm adding items to list and after Itemsource is this list and I'm binding it to textboxes

```
 var str = new StreamReader(contentStream);

            while(str.EndOfStream !=true)
            {

                string line = str.ReadLine();
                if (line == null)
                    break;
               var spl = line.Split(';');
               string prvni = spl[0].ToString();

                if(spl[0]!="")
                {
               if (spl[0].Substring(0,3).Contains("-"))
               {
                   obj.Add(new data(a+pocet.ToString(),spl[0].ToString(), spl[1].ToString(), spl[2].ToString(),"#FF00D1FF"));
               }

               else
                   obj.Add(new data(a+pocet.ToString(),spl[0].ToString(), spl[1].ToString(), spl[2].ToString(), "White"));
            }
                else
                {
                    obj.Add(new data(a + pocet.ToString(), spl[0].ToString(), spl[1].ToString(), spl[2].ToString(), "White"));
                }




               pocet++;
            }



            br.ItemsSource = obj;  // load list to binding
```

Class data

```
public class data
{
public string Index { get; set; }
public string s1 { get; set; }
public string s2 { get; set; }
public string s3 { get; set; }
public string color { get; set; }

public data() { }

public data(string index,string s1, string s2, string s3, string br)
{
    this.Index = index;

    this.s1 = s1;
    this.s2 = s2;
    this.s3 = s3;
    this.color = br;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also worked with dynamic content and I used to do this: ( Adapted to your requirements )

```
// Cycle through every control from Ahoj
foreach (Object controlObject in Ahoj.Children) {
    if (controlObject is TextBox) {
        TextBox
            textBox = controlObject as TextBox;

        // Do your stuff here...
    }
}
```

Since you say that you're unable to access the `Grid` directly ( if I understood correctly, you're adding the control by run-time code ) then you can do something like this:

```
try {
    Grid
        grid = FindName("Ahoj") as Grid;

    // Cycle through every control from Ahoj
    foreach (Object controlObject in grid.Children) {
        if (controlObject is TextBox) {
            TextBox
                textBox = controlObject as TextBox;

            // Do your stuff here...
        }
    }
} catch (Exception exception) {
    // Unable to catch or cast the object
}
```

**EDIT:** If you also need to know the position of each `TextBox` you may use a `for(;;)` instead.

**EDIT 15 Jan 2016:** Here is the code updated based on what's been discused on comments and with the sudden realization that you could simply get the `List` binded to the control since the beginning:

```
try {
    List<data>
        dataList = br.ItemsSource;

    /*
        Do your stuff here ...
    */
} catch(Exception exception) {
    // Unable to get the previously binded items
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well, but  this code working only with first grid...I need text from all grids that I create. I'm creating about 20 grids (the same name, but diferent values in textBoxes) (I have editet my post)

Comment: Can you show part of the code where you add the grids? I'm 100% sure that you can't add controls with the same name on the same page.

Comment: Clarify me just one thing: You're adding multiple `ItemsControl` to a, let's say, `StackPanel` or similar control, right? If you're something like that, why don't you simply cicle through the control children?

If you are indeed doing something like I said, please say it and I'll update my answer with a solution that might work.

Comment: Yeah, you are right... sorry for wrong description.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but this is no solution for my problem. With this code i get original values from ItemSource, but table is editable and user can change all values in table so I need to get actual  values. 
For example: First line will be: "test, test, test" - user change it to: "test, example, today" and with ItemSource to List I get original values "test, test, test" not changed values

Comment: Try it again, but this time where you have `{Binding /* something */}` try to change to `{Binding /* something */, Mode=TwoWay}`. Example: {Binding s1, Mode=TwoWay}

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are asking but if you want to create a list of all the strings in the textboxes you can do the following:

Loop through each visual child element of the "Ahoj" grid (using VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(container, index)) and check if it is a TextBox Type. In case it is request the Text property of the TextBox and add it to the list of strings.

See [MSDN VisualTreeHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper) for more info.

Comment: A tryed it, but I can not acces to this grid called "ahoj" because it is into datatemplate. Code is:     IEnumerable<Grid> collection = ahoj.Children.OfType<Grid>(); (but i can't acces to this grid ... )